# How many Kanjis do we learn in middle school?

Tags: kanji

I just wanted to know and I was wondering how many kanjis we learn in the middle school in Japan?

こんにちは！さっき、そういえばとおもったんですが、中学校では漢字を何文字ぐらい習うんですか？

Comment: As far as I understand there is no fixed number, although I imagine that until the end of middle school (= the end of 義務教育) you should learn all 常用漢字.

Comment: I agree with @Earthliŋ: I always thought how many you learned in middle school corresponded to how many jouyou kanji there are in general.

Answer (score 3):

> http://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/3429282.html
>
> 常用漢字は２千字程度と認識していますが、 . . .
>
> 文部科学省が定める、中学校学習指導要領に記載があります。 . . .
>
> つまり、小学校までで1千字、中学までで2000字弱と言うことですね。

1-6th grade :  1000 Kanji's

almost 1000 more in the next 3 years of school.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a list of kanjis students in Japanese schools learn per year.
You can find it here
http://kanjitisiki.com/tyugako/
or alternatively, just google 漢字リスト中学校 or whatever school respectively.
But yes, around 1000 kanjis in 3 years of middle school.